# Defining command similar to AtBeginDocument

Tags: macros

I want to define command `\AfterAtBeginDocument` that acts similar to `\AtBeginDocument`: collects code and then puts it right after what `AtBeginDocument` produces.

So, the code

```
\AfterAtBeginDocument{
    2
}

\AtBeginDocument{
    1
}

\begin{document}

    3
    
\end{document}
```

should produce `123`

This is MWE, but I don't know what to do with `\AtBeginDocument`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\AfterAtBeginDocumentText}{}{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\AfterAtBeginDocument}{ +m }{%
    \let\tmpAfterAtBeginDocumentText\AfterAtBeginDocumentText
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\AfterAtBeginDocumentText}{}{\tmpAfterAtBeginDocumentText#1}%
}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\AtBeginDocument}{ +m }{}


\AfterAtBeginDocument{
    2
}

\AtBeginDocument{
    1
}

\begin{document}

    3
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: What exactly is the use case for this? Note that the new kernes have `\AtBeginDocument` implemented via the new hookign system. That system can reorder its contents.

Comment: @daleif I want to be sure that a code is executed after `\AtBeginDocument`. I am having some problems with `babel` definitions that are set via `\AtBeginDocument`

Comment: @MichaelFraiman Sounds like a job for the hook system

Comment: @JosephWright I do not know what it is

Comment: @MichaelFraiman With the new hook system, something like `\AtBeginDocument[mycode]{<your code here>} \DeclareHookRule{begindocument}{mycode}{after}{babel}`.  A real example that shows your problem with `babel` would help towards a more concrete answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With new LaTeX kernel you can use `\AddToHook{begindocument/end}`.

```
\documentclass{article}


\def\AfterAtBeginDocument{\AddToHook {begindocument/end}}

\AfterAtBeginDocument{2}
\AtBeginDocument{1}

\begin{document}
    3
    
\end{document}
```